# How to decode Ethereum raw transaction

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm trying to decode the following raw transaction, and I have already analyze some of the information, can anyone please tell me the logic behind it?
0x02f902fa0181b483a6792e850244ddce8e83045ee9943fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad8802c68af0bb140000b902843593564c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006508457f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020b080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c68af0bb1400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c68af0bb140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001886271c2fb90c220a4d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20000000000000000000000003850952491606a0e420eb929b1a2e1a450d013f1c001a08b50ee3e376edb0fc0719ecb19a38dd7558285ba61b15c30083369bb76bfb393a069dc859312719259201ffae0c78208abc1b4e93ed05fd782f754dbe9eec75231

I have tried to decode it by comparing the JSON data and the raw transaction it self so I have already done some of the analyzing, however, I still need help to decode the black words in the picture I have uploaded.

[I have analyze so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq4na.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

- You need the smart contract ABI files to decode the transaction
- You need a framework and library that can take ABI files and your Data payload and decode it for you
- One library, for example, [is Web.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and its [decode_function_input](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.contract.html#web3.contract.Contract.decode_function_input) function but there are others

[For more information, see the smart contract development frameworks at Ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/frameworks/).

Answer (score 0):

You can decode your raw tx hex here: https://rawtxdecode.in

Here is what it is showing for your tx hex:

```
{
  "chainId": "1",
  "type": "EIP-1559",
  "valid": true,
  "hash": "0x9d0de6855390ff87e9fe9ca8a8e07e6a8819f29531ea69dc701f96268080440d",
  "nonce": "180",
  "gasLimit": "286441",
  "maxFeePerGas": "9745321614",
  "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "10909998",
  "from": "0x7C71e3C2dC48557336961e0adc390164C8b045b6",
  "to": "0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
  "publicKey": "0x042e53305a01238bbb049d4f4d4c06b9aabaf42297bb2368f9263fb2e155fd9fce02bdd0e0e1a97632e4da7e11605423563a70fe78c146ab4ee89f234204f60d0c",
  "v": "01",
  "r": "8b50ee3e376edb0fc0719ecb19a38dd7558285ba61b15c30083369bb76bfb393",
  "s": "69dc859312719259201ffae0c78208abc1b4e93ed05fd782f754dbe9eec75231",
  "value": "200000000000000000",
  "data": "0x3593564c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006508457f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020b080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c68af0bb1400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c68af0bb140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001886271c2fb90c220a4d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20000000000000000000000003850952491606a0e420eb929b1a2e1a450d013f1",
  "functionHash": "0x3593564c",
  "possibleFunctions": [
    {
      "definition": "execute(bytes,bytes[],uint256)",
      "decodedInputs": [
        "0b08",
        [
          "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c68af0bb140000",
          "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c68af0bb140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001886271c2fb90c220a4d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20000000000000000000000003850952491606a0e420eb929b1a2e1a450d013f1"
        ],
        "1695040895"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```